# React how to add custom js file web application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

Styles and  Js file how to add in react ,
I developed a template using  html css js , 
now i want to switch all to react , 
i have assets files and how i will change to react .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can include react to html file by  including

And you can include your components to the app using

The css you can link easily the only difference is, instead of keyword "class" on tags you should use "classname"

You can refer the react documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-react-in-one-minute